# Feature (bugfix?) request for Furigana

Tags: bug, status-completed, furigana

In a Japanese sentence, am I missing something, or is it currently not possible to add Furigana to the second set of Kanji onwards without adding Furigana to the whole sentence up until that point?

For example as at [How to express: I am going to Japan to study?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/), in the following sentence, can just `留学{りゅうがく}` be annotated without annotating everything before it, or would it be possible for the functionality to be added to support it?

Here's how that looks unformatted:

```
私は日本に留学{りゅうがく}つもりです。
```

Here's how that is formatted currently:

`私は日本に留学{りゅうがく}つもりです。`

Comment: I have no idea why I put hiraganas into kanji list, I will fix it soon. In the mean time, you could put kanjis into square brackets to prevent that happens (`私は日本に[留学]\{りゅうがく}つもりです。`)

Comment: @YOU What is the backslash for? Is it for escaping `{` to show the source code rather than formatted ruby?

Comment: @sawa, yes, you're right. I was lazy to find better formatting to show that.

Comment: I'm double checking something with @jmac before I post an answer, but I don't think there's anything we need to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put [] brackets around the kanji you want to add furigana to.  The script parser is probably confused about for which set of kanji the reading is intended.

> 私わたしは日本に[留学]{りゅうがく}つもりです。

```
私わたしは日本に[留学] {りゅうがく}つもりです。
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this was fixed at some point, so the formatter *should* properly take the preceeding kanji without needing the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to overcome this. That is to enclose the word that you want the furigana to be hovering over in square brackets - e.g. [留学], followed by the furigana in the squiggly brackets - {りゅうがく}.

It will look something like 私は日本に[留学] {りゅうがく}つもりです.